# How to crack Sharepoint Online document links to its actual url

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, links

Its so annoying Sharepoint online now has copy link which creates this GUID which i have no clue where it orginated from.

https://turainc.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/tura/EQL4ibXUPv9Cr8E0KAUF0XkBJm76vuQmhAgFDXXlNSXh9A?e=qUH7JL

Above document address how can i crack this to find out where does this exists in my site?

Answer (score 1):

To get the decrypted Url use the following link:

**Absolute Url + Path to file/folder + file name**

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + /Shared Documents + /test1.pdf
```

**Example**:

https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/test1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since the address which get from “Copy Link” button is an encryption URL, it will protect the files and libraries from viewing and editing by anonymous who doesn’t have any access.

Based on my knowledge, we are not able to get the document information directly via the address.

Actually, if we sign in with relevant account and have permission with the document, it will display the relevant site and document library name when we open the file via the address:

[image]

Comment: I am having issue where i click on existing link reference in a excel  document in sharepoint online i get this message:  This link has bene removed: Sorry access to this cdocument has been removed. Please contact the person who shared it with you"  But i am Office 365 global admin. Why am i getting this message?

Comment: it might caused by providing read access to a document that uses draft item security. You can contact the person as the error message mentioned to check if the document use draft item security. Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-sorry-you-cannot-access-this-document-error-when-a-guest-link-is-used-to-access-a-sharepoint-online-document-39ba7646-3d56-4a0c-ba36-4c476e77162e

Answer (score 0):

To view a clean Office document URL and determine where a file lives, open the file in the desktop application and click the **File** tab.  In the **Info** section, click the site and library name and then select **Copy path to clipboard**.  Paste the link somewhere and you can now figure out where the document is housed.

For screenshots, view my post, [Get a clean document URL](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sharepoint-online-get-clean-document-urls-bypass-encryption-or-sharing-url/).